# pathspec 'v2.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, hyperledger-fabric

I got an error when I [**downloaded the fabric samples.**](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

[The command I used to download the latest fabric samples.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl7bw.png)

The error is

```
pathspec 'v2.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I am not familar with git and I've searched on the internet but didn't get the idea. Hope you guys give me a help. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The [`hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh) does a `git checkout v${VERSION}`, with `version` being set to `2.0.0`.

If you see the message "Cloning hyperledger/fabric-samples" just before the error message, this matches:

> ```
> echo "===> Cloning hyperledger/fabric-samples repo and checkout v${VERSION}"
> git clone -b master https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git && cd fabric-samples && git checkout v${VERSION}
> ```

That means you need to go in that `fabric-samples` folder, and chose another tag for the `git checkout` part ([listed here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/releases)): there is no `v2.0.0` yet.